# Last chance at jQuery AJAX Toggle

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I posted this question ealier today, however I recieved a fix (thank you) that works great against my RequestBin endpoint for testing, however when submitting to my AJAX script, its a different story.

**Problem:** I cant submit my jQuery toggle values to my PHP AJAX script because there is no form name associated with the POST request (so db never updates). I proven this by making a HTML form with the field names and the database updated right away. However this is not the case with this JS toggle method.

jQuery code

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.switch').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this).toggleClass("switchOn");
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "https://--------.x.pipedream.net/",
             data: {
                value: $this.hasClass("switchOn") ? 'pagination' : 'infinite'
             },
             success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
             }
         });
     });
   });
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-toggle" align="center">
   <label>
      <div class="switch"></div>
      <div class="switch-label">Use <b>Paged</b> results instead (Current: <b>Infinite</b>)</div>
   </label>
</div>
```

PHP AJAX script

```
    if (array_key_exists('pagination', $_POST)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET browse_mode = 'pagination' WHERE user_id = 1");
        //$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $account->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
    } else if (array_key_exists('infinite', $_POST)) { 
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET browse_mode = 'infinite' WHERE user_id = 1");
        //$stmt->bindParam(":user_id", $account->getId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute(); 
    }
```

I cant figure out how to assign a field name to this, as it is not a traditional post form. This is driving me nuts. So the previous solution was applying hasClass() and calling var $this outside of $ajax(), great (and RequestBin receives both requests), but when submitting to PHP its a dead end (no form names).

Given the code above fixed and revised twice, where do I even start without a **form** ??

**We need:**
name="pagination"
name="infinite"

But this toggle JS doesn't allow for this. **prop()** has been removed to get toggle submitting values over (just not my AJAX script).

Any solution appreciated. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your values as Form Data. So the PHP Function will get it just like a traditional form submission:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.switch').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this).toggleClass("switchOn");
         var formdata = new FormData();
         $this.hasClass("switchOn") ? formdata.append('pagination', 'name') : formdata.append('infinite', 'name');
         
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "https://--------.x.pipedream.net/",
             data: formdata,
             success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
             }
         });
     });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

More info on JS Form Data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Absolutely no data both ways using your code. i do understand what is going on with this code you posted, but neither the endpoint or the script see's anything happening, and i even created the hidden inputs wrapped in a form just in case, the console tells me nothing as well. Dead end...

Comment: what do you get if you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I have updated a column in my table with $_POST from var_dump and its NULL so that tells me nothing is coming over (again no form names and only the code I posted is working for a endpoint service for debugging AJAX calls